# Are Powershell's New-NetFirewallRule and Set-NetFirewallRule inconsistent?

Tags: windows, powershell-v5.0

I noticed that the PowerShell `New-NetFirewallRule` cmdlet does not behave like I expected. When calling the commandlet repeatedly, it will create multiple entries with the same name.

For example, when running this command twice `New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Website" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 80 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow`, will give two of the same firewall entries.

Should commands with the [`New` verb](https://docs.microsoft.com/nl-nl/powershell/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) not fail when the resource already exists?

When `New-NetFirewallRule` retuns an object with the firewall rule, `Set-NetFirewallRule` returns nothing.

Running `Set-NetFirewallRule` does not work for creating a new rule. It will raise an error which says that the resource does not exist. I expected a `Set` verb updates or creates the resource.

Using PowerShell 5.1 on Windows Server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that "DisplayName" is not the same as "Name" parameter, name must be unique, display name can repeat it self.

You are using `DisplayName` so it's not an error, try it with `Name` and you'll get what you want. an Error of duplicate entry.